# How to add new object in object class using prompt input in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```
class Person {
    constructor(fname, lname, brithdate) {
        this.firsName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
        this.dov = brithdate;
    }
}


let person1 = new Person("Alifa", "Elham", "12-07-2000");

let person2 = new Person("Mazdul", "Prodhan", "07-03-2000");

console.log(person1);

function addNewPerson() {
    let ffname = prompt("enter your firstname");
    let llname = prompt("enter your lastname");
    let ddov = prompt("enter your date of birth");

return new Person(ffname, llname, ddov);
}
```

How can add new object to my Person object class using promt input .And it will have name like i creat person1,person3. I want to create new object like person 3,4,5 and it will go on. maybe using loop .
**Help me , I am a new learner of javasctipt**

Comment: That return statement should be inside the `addNewPerson` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the `Person` object inside the `addNewPerson` function, since the `ffname`, `llname` and `ddov` variables are confined to the scope of that function, and because it's an illegal `return` statement otherwise.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(fname, lname, brithdate) {
    this.firsName = fname;
    this.lastName = lname;
    this.dov = brithdate;
  }
}


let person1 = new Person("Alifa", "Elham", "12-07-2000");

let person2 = new Person("Mazdul", "Prodhan", "07-03-2000");

function addNewPerson() {
  let ffname = prompt("enter your firstname");
  let llname = prompt("enter your lastname");
  let ddov = prompt("enter your date of birth");

  return new Person(ffname, llname, ddov);
}

console.log(addNewPerson())
```

Comment: its working , but how can I add  object with name like person3,person4 ......everytime it will add +1 to person name

Comment: whenever I call addNewPerson function